# Term for the moment when hydrogen fusion begins in a star

Tags: star-formation, terminology

I have read of this process many times, but I don't think I know the term specifically for the moment when hydrogen fusion begins. What is this moment called?

Comment: How about ignition? Or [fusion ignition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusion_ignition)?

Comment: James got it below, I think. "Stellar ignition" is a search term that brings up many more relevant hits than I was seeing before. Stellar ignition is technically fusion ignition, but there are other consequences to stellar ignition specific to star and star system formation.

Comment: Yes, "stellar ignition" is a little more specific than "fusion ignition".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Ignition** or more fully [Stellar ignition](http://www.schoolsobservatory.org.uk/learn/astro/stars/formation) is the term you want.

Comment: I presume this has never been witnessed, but no harm asking if you know of such an event been recorded.

Comment: Yes indeed, that's what I was after. :) Thank you! If anyone comes across a more specific term, I'd love to see it. For now stellar ignition is sufficient.

Comment: @StephenG there is no "event" or moment of ignition. The timescales suggested here are quite incorrect for hydrogen fusion commencement.

Answer (score 5):

It is known as the nuclear turn-on in the Hertzsprung-Russell diagram; the opposite of the nuclear turn-off when hydrogen is exhausted in the core.

In actual fact there is no "moment" when the star begins to fuse hydrogen, it is a gradual process.

For example, the models of [Siess et al. (2001)](http://www.astro.ulb.ac.be/~siess/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/StellarModels/Z02) suggest that a solar mass pre main sequence star gets 0.01% of its luminosity from hydrogen fusion at 2 million years old,  1% after 16 million years, but it is not until it is 56 million years old that 99% of the luminosity comes from hydrogen fusion.

Answer (score 2):

The onset of hydrogen fusion for a star (i.e. when it enters the main sequence) is called the [zero-age main sequence](https://en.mimi.hu/astronomy/zero-age_main_sequence.html) (ZAMS). Conversely, the terminal-age main sequence (TAMS) refers to the point a star stops fusing hydrogen (and by definition leaves the main sequence); the time between the ZAMS and TAMS is called the main sequence lifetime. On the Hurtzsprung-Russell diagram, several stars at their ZAMS are grouped into a line:

[image]

<sup>Picture from [Evolution from the Main Sequence to Red Giants](http://cnx.org/contents/im49RUTc@4/Evolution-from-the-Main-Sequen), courtesy of Rice University under a [Creative Commons Attribution License 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/).</sup>

Some astronomers consider the ZAMS to be the "birth" of a star, in the sense that the object is no longer a protostar and meets the criteria of a star ([source](https://astronomy.swin.edu.au/cosmos/Z/Zero+Age+Main+Sequence)). These astronomers thus consider a star's age to be the time between now and its ZAMS. However, this is simply a matter of terminology, as others consider the formation of the star to be the moment when its molecular cloud collapses.

Comment: This is *a* definition, but the star is still contracting for some period of time, whilst generating energy from fusion, *before* it reaches the ZAMS.

Comment: @RobJeffries As far as I know, ZAMS only refers to when hydrogen fusion begins, which is what the OP is asking about.

Comment: No it does not. It refers to the point at which hydrostatic equlibrium is achieved and the star stops contracting.

Comment: @RobJeffries Several sources apparently say it refers to when hydrogen burning begins, as well. ([1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/9908291.pdf), [2](http://cnx.org/contents/im49RUTc@4/Evolution-from-the-Main-Sequen),
 [3](https://astronomy.swin.edu.au/cosmos/Z/Zero+Age+Main+Sequence), [4](https://en.mimi.hu/astronomy/zero-age_main_sequence.html))

Comment: From your source (1) "Accordingly, all these “Zero Age” models have
already experienced a phase of nuclear burning, with time
scales which largely depend on the stellar mass". Exactly.

Comment: @RobJeffries I might be mistaken, but couldn't nuclear burning refer to deuterium or lithium burning?

Comment: And Siess's isochrone server defines the ZAMS "as the time, after deuterium burning, when the nuclear luminosity provides at least 99% of the total stellar luminosity, i.e. when Lnucl > 0.99 L". The ZAMS is the minimum luminosity point in the HR diagram when contraction ceases. It is when H-burning becomes utterly dominant, not when it commences. The difference is perhaps <1% of the main sequence lifetime, but that is still of order 50 million years for a star like the Sun.

Comment: @RobJeffries Hmm...the paper says "stellar models which are just starting central H burning with the timescale of H consumption." The source from [Rice University](http://cnx.org/contents/im49RUTc@4/Evolution-from-the-Main-Sequen) says "We use the term zero-age to mark the time when a star stops contracting, settles onto the main sequence, and begins to fuse hydrogen in its core." The one from [Swinburne](https://astronomy.swin.edu.au/cosmos/Z/Zero+Age+Main+Sequence) says 
 "when a star first...[burns] hydrogen in its core". Is it possible that the term is ambiguous, or just misused?

Comment: Read the rest of the section. The quote I supplied comes from a few lines further on. Are you attempting to argue that a star stops contracting and only then does H fusion begin? I have given the numbers from a published stellar evolutionary code in my answer. The figures are not even vaguely controversial.